# "The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?" error when installing Python using pyenv

Tags: python, 18.04

While installing Python using pyenv, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873193/error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib-inst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the python version you are trying to install is equal or lower than 2.7.12, it does not support OpenSSL1.1.0, so you would need to replace `libssl-dev` with `libssl1.0-dev`.

Ubuntu 18.04 is the first official release to switch to OpenSSL1.1.0 which is why you might not have been impacted with this in the past.

Reference:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/945

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/common-build-problems#error-the-python-ssl-extension-was-not-compiled-missing-the-openssl-lib

Answer (score 0):

check you version: `openssl version`
pyenv install 3.9 #ok
pyenv install 3.10 #error
Currently Python versions 3.6 to 3.9 are compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.2,
1.1.0, and 1.1.1. For the most part Python also works with LibreSSL >= 2.7.1
with some missing features and broken tests.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/install.html), a simple:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

should do the job. If `pip` is not installed, run

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

and then run the command again.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Can you suggest some other solution?